# Postgres table id duplicate when exist primary key unique constraint

Tags: java, database, postgresql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

### Question in Log

1. question occur in spring data jpa component. there is a log say:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: a9d3e53c-efe2-4945-a034-f2d045fe6cce, for class: com.***.model.User
```

And I look up my db, find the duplicate data. what happened? why there exist two same id user?

### Table schema

```
---------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id                  | uuid                     |           | not null |
 blocked             | boolean                  |           | not null |
 is_admin            | boolean                  |           |          |
 is_root             | boolean                  |           |          |
 last_login_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 nick_name           | text                     |           |          |
 pass_word           | character varying(255)   |           |          |
 register_at         | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 user_name           | character varying(255)   |           |          |
 app_image           | text                     |           |          |
 avatar              | text                     |           |          |
 birth_day           | text                     |           |          |
 city                | text                     |           |          |
 front_blocked       | boolean                  |           |          |
 gender              | smallint                 |           |          |
 intro               | text                     |           |          |
 is_vest             | boolean                  |           |          |
 phone               | text                     |           |          |
 web_image           | text                     |           |          |
 wrap_vest           | boolean                  |           |          |
 wx_mini_app_open_id | text                     |           |          |
 wx_open_id          | text                     |           |          |
 wx_union_id         | text                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uk_589idila9li6a4arw1t8ht1gx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (phone)
    "uk__user__phone" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (phone)
    "uk__user__wx_union_id" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (wx_union_id)
    "uk_lqjrcobrh9jc8wpcar64q1bfh" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (user_name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "role" CONSTRAINT "fkahi3iro2tsdvjif5c499jg8rv" FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
    TABLE "role_users" CONSTRAINT "fkarktlgi8f51hau76pfku4noat" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
    TABLE "exception" CONSTRAINT "fkkd502yhn3ji8bqecwd4yax0gk" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
    TABLE "version_management" CONSTRAINT "fktd43egsseixxvg2j59irwunid" FOREIGN KEY (created_by_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)
```

### Group result

```
=# select id, count(*) from "user" group by id;
                  id                  | count
--------------------------------------+-------
 062e8528-0b6c-465c-b883-ac513ad41442 |     1
 122881d5-9d28-49b9-b488-61575e41b4e7 |     1
 f3603aa6-76bc-431f-81a4-e06d4c0bfad2 |     1
 93102a40-a82f-4e6e-8a7a-ecbf9f9c2b29 |     1
 2b5d9bd7-222d-4e44-9897-159726c533c0 |     1
 bf91105d-bbfc-4dbe-93d6-b580e13100b8 |     1
 f7a6c129-5df1-41e8-8847-99c553a701fa |     1
 a9d3e53c-efe2-4945-a034-f2d045fe6cce |     2
 507873de-fc12-4bd1-bf93-a2ded7ac8d88 |     1
 29646dd8-ffc7-4fff-a708-e3f3bef64b28 |     1
```

Comment: Shouldn't primary key defined this way - 
"id" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be experiencing data corruption.

You'll have to dump the database and restore it to a newly created PostgreSQL cluster, and you have to clean up the duplicates manually.

Then you best investigate what might have caused the problem. Were there recent crashes? Is the hardware (disk, memory) ok? Did you restore from a backup or activate a standby server? It might also be helpful to find the latest backup that doesn't have the data corruption and recapitulate what you changed since.

Comment: thanks, It work now after I dropped and created database. I guess the problem maybe caused by cloud server scale.